# How to display many to many relationship with nsfetchedresultcontroller?

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

If I use a one to many, I can display all the associated NSSet records but many to many doesn't seem to work the same.

On my segue I pass the gymnast to a VC in which I would like to display all associated meets which works fine in a one to many.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if let objs = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects where objs.count > 0 {

            let item = objs[indexPath.row] as! Gymnast

            performSegueWithIdentifier("displayMeets", sender: item)
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "displayMeets" {

            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! SelectMeetVC

            vc.selectedGymnast = sender as? Gymnast
        }
    }
```

I get a crash unless I comment out the NSPREDICATE

```
func loadFetchRequest() {

        self.fetchedResultsController = nil

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Meet")

        let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "meetName", ascending: true)

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1]

        //let filter = NSPredicate(format: "gymnasts.fullName == %@", "\(selectedGymnast.fullName!)")

        //fetchRequest.predicate = filter

        let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: AD.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        controller.delegate = self

        fetchedResultsController = controller

        do {

            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()

        } catch {

            fatalError("Error retrieving core data")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `gymnasts` relationship is to-many, you need to amend the predicate so that it selects a `Meet` if *any* of its `gymnasts` matches:

```
let filter = NSPredicate(format: "ANY gymnasts.fullName == %@", "\(selectedGymnast.fullName!)")
```

Note also that there's no need to use the `fullName` attribute - you can match the `Gymnast` object itself:

```
let filter = NSPredicate(format: "ANY gymnasts == %@", selectedGymnast)
```